# Inserting a DropDown Menu

Tags: outsystems

I need some suggestion on handling an issues. I have an entity called Rider with an Integer attribute called PayPeriod and another Date attribute called DateToRide. So this PayPeriod for Rider gets populated from the Static entity called Pay_Period with Attributes PayPrd, PayStartDate and PayEndDate and Records from Pay1 to Pay26.
[image]

So what happens is once Date to Ride is entered for a Rider the PayPeriod from static entity Pay_Period is calculated like, in Action for creating a new Rider

```
NewRider.DateToRide >= Pay_Period.PayStartDate and NewRider.DateToRide <= Pay_Period.PayEndDate
```

And it is assigned like
[image]

It looks in the table like this

[image]

Now there is a requirement also to add a drop down menu in the page where the user should be able to change the payperiod 1 t0 26 for a Rider. So I am trying to add a drop down but the issue is I am not having the foreignkey Pay_Period Identifier in my Rider entity so
[image]
Not sure what is the Variable I will be giving here. I tried creating the local variable of Pay_Period Identifier type and liked to the Dropdown variable but it doesnot work that way.Can anyone spot light on how to approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why it didn't work to use a local variable with the type Pay_Period identifier. It should, cause that's the way to dot it :). That's the variable that will hold the value selected by the user. Check my test:
[ComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ6m3.png)

And the variable declaration

[variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG15z.png)